# Laravel Best Security for Saving New Instance with foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I'm tried to find a better security for saving new instance with foreign key.
I've got 2 solutions with both give me the same result.

First one is get the foreign key value directly from request input.

```
$post= new Post();
$post->post = $request->post
    $post->article_id = $request->article_id;
    $post->user_id  = $request->user_id;
    $post->save();
```

Second one tried to find it first and using associate.

```
    $post= new Post(['post' => $request->post]);
    $post->article()->associate($request->article_id);
    $post->user()->associate($request->user_id);
    $post->save();
```

Well, second approach is longer than first one.
Is there any drawback for using first one or second one such as security, performance, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the user_id from the $request(which i assume is your $_POST'ed values?) you risk that people substitute their own user_id for an ID belonging to another player. I would recommend you taking the user_id from your active authorization. Something like this perhaps?:

```
Auth::user->id
```

Taking a user_id from the $request only makes sense if the caller is allowed to post for other people (such as admin functions for instance).

Aside from that, either approach seems fine. I would have probably preferred to use method 1 over 2, just to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Hi, I can't user `Auth::user->id` because my application is seperate from laravel. Laravel will send the specific user_id for token that sent from front-end. And my application will merge a request from middleware.

Comment: Ah okay. As long as you're sure the user_id is correct and cannot be manipulated by the user, then there are no security issue there. To elaborate then, method 2 seems most "eloquent". If you have massive cascading features that requires Eloquent to handle them when associating, then that's the way to go. If not, i still think method 1 is the preferrable one, due to simplicity. Never over-complicate if you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks @Avenar it really help me. Will stick to first approach :)